# Need to use Remote Kendo Grouped and Stacked Bar Chart

Tags: kendo-chart

I am using Kendo Bar Chart, which will show like grouped and stacked for dynamic data. In category field i need to display usernames and it has to show respective metric values, here metric values are dynamic and variable, and metric count values are displayed in bar, which is like stacked bar.

For Example: 
Metric values are - High, Low, Medium, ...
Metric values count -> High-4, Low-2, and medium -5 ,..
Here counts 4,2, and 5 to be shown in a stacked bar.

Like this i have to show for multiple users with respective the values.
Below i have shown my Code, may i know how to use dynamic stacked bar kendo chart, and can i have solution for above mentioned problem.

Code- Chart Definition

```
$("#chartForWorkItems").kendoChart({

    title: {
        text: "Bugs State Analysis"
    },
    //defining the datasource for loading the chart
    dataSource: {
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: baseUri + "ProjectReportWorkItemChart/chartDisplayForWorkITems",
                cache: false,
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                complete: function (e) {




                },
            },
            parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                console.log(selectedCategoryByMetrics);
                if (operation == "read") {
                    return {
                        workItems: selectedCategoryByMetrics,
                        Projectid: sessionStorage.getItem("prjprojectid"),
                        metricsWithWorkItem: metricsWithWorkItem,
                        users: usersSelected
                    }
                }
            },


        },
        schema: {
            model: {
                id: "field",
                fields: {
                    field: { type: "string" },
                    count_f: { type: "string" },
                    metric: { type: "string" },
                    assignedTo: { type: "string" },
                }
            }
        }
    },
    chartArea: {
        width: 400,
        height: 300,
    },
    seriesDefaults: {
        type: "column",

    },
    series: [{
        field: "count_f",

    },

    ],
    categoryAxis: {
           categories: "assignedTo",
        field: "field",
        majorGridLines: {
            visible: true
        }
    },

    valueAxis: [{                 //display count in the value axis
        line: {
            visible: true
        },
        majorGridLines: {
            visible: true
        }

    }],
    tooltip: {                      //To display tool tip
        visible: true
    },
});
```

Comment: Hi, did you ever find a solution to this as this is something I'm looking into as well at the moment?